Why std::stable_sort does not compile when std::sort does?
The code below fails to compile on GCC and CLang (msvc fails because of the experimental/propagate_const).
It is just PoC. Imagine the type X being complex, comparison operator meaningful and vector m non-empty.
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <experimental/propagate_const>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class X {};

std::shared_ptr<X> simplify(std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<X>>& i) {
   return get_underlying(i);
}

int operator<=>(const std::shared_ptr<X>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<X>& rhs) {
   return 0;
}

void swap(std::shared_ptr<X> lhs, std::shared_ptr<X> rhs) {
   std::swap(lhs, rhs);
}

int main() {
   std::vector<std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<X>>> m;
   decltype(m | std::views::transform(simplify)) r = m | std::views::transform(simplify);
   std::sort(r.begin(), r.end()); // compiles
   std::stable_sort(r.begin(), r.end()); // ERROR: no matching function for call to ‘__rotate`...
}

https://godbolt.org/z/oWP7G1Ths
What is so special in std::stable_sort that it prevents compilation? How should I implement the __rotate?

Share the traceback error.

Adam: In the future, remember to add the [tag:c++] tag too. Not everyone subscribes to the version specific tags, like [tag:c++20].

Unfortunately (or fortunately) __rotate is not a customization point. The most you can do is to customize swap, but I think your swap is problematic, because your element types are the shared pointers not the underlying values.

@alfC The swap function looks fine although a tad expensive. I'd use references there.

It's just too bad that it actually compiles with that std::sort since it actually doesn't manage to sort the range. Simplified demo

Yes, that is what I am trying to say, the OP is confusing what means to sort values. I think he tries to implement some kind of reference counted value, but shared_ptr is no for that, it needs to be further wrapped. Or a different container needs to be used such as Boost.PtrContainer, which I don't recommend anyway.
Also the definition of swap is not even necessary for make it compile: https://godbolt.org/z/oWP7G1Ths

std::rotate/std::ranges::rotate needs references to be able to swap elements, but your transform_view return copies (via simplify).
The requirements for std::rotate:

ForwardIt must be ValueSwappable.
The type of *first must be MoveConstructible.
The type of *first must be MoveAssignable.

This fails for copies since you can't move assign a temporary. std::sort has the same requirements so the usage of std::sort in your program has undefined behavior - even though it seems to work.
Make simplify return a reference:
std::shared_ptr<X>& simplify(std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<X>>& i) {
//                ^
    return get_underlying(i);
}

Demo

I just asked a question in Slack Cpp. It is very strange that rotate requires move-constructible, since the only thing it does (or it should do?) is swaps.

My impression is that rotate requires moveassignable to reserve the right in an hypothetical implementation to do certain optimization tricks in particular cases (e.g. rotate-by-one). An optimization that you can see in the __insertion_sort auxiliary function. I know because it is not optimal for a certain library that I am developing and it is giving me a hard time.

I think it is a bad (non-generic) optimization anyway, and it messes up with reasonable requirements, it is really bad IMO that a requirement is added for an optimization. sort, stable_sort and rotate should all simply work with swappable and only use the tricks if other operations (e.g. move) are available and are no except.

Move is how swapping is properly done. Otherwise you must either resort to making copies or playing bit-twiddling hacks which will obviously break.

Yes, and it may also be hard to swap in-place (without constructing a copy). std::swap requires both MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable. shared_ptr of course has a special swap to not have to do that, so why the requirement leaks out to std::sort and std::rotate I don't know straight up.

Thank you, @TedLyngmo! That solves half of my actual problem: what if I also have a simplify's sibling that is called get_const, and returns std::shared_ptr<const X>? In this situation, I can't return the reference, and still cannot stable-sort the non-const vector of smart pointers to const.

@AdamRyczkowski Great! If this answer answered the question you asked, I suggest that you ask a new question for the scenario you describe. I don't think it'll be answerable in a comment.

@Dúthomhas, not always. even now that by default swaps are implemented with move, there are certain types that are better (and more correctly implemented) in a different way. Think for example, std::array or tuples of references.

@alfC gcc's std::array::swap uses std::swap_ranges, which uses std::iter_swap which ultimately may use std::swap if there's no user-defined swap overload for the type in question - and then the type must be MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable.

@TedLyngmo, well, yes, it is turtles all the way down. What I am saying is that it is not trying to make a temporary of type std::array. The concept ultimately will be checked/demanded on the element type.

@alfC Yes, the type in the array still has the requirements since it (std::array::swap) needs to make or move one element at a time (using std::swap that is).
